# Error en la linea 10 de mi código de Python

Tags: python, anaconda

Me sale lo siguiente al tratar de correr el codigo:

File "C:\Users\ISEJA\Documents\Python Scripts\orbitas.py", line 10, in 
Tiempo=text(pos=(0,0.9,0), depth=-0.01, color=color.green, height=0.1)

File "C:\Users\ISEJA\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\vpython\vpython.py", line 3860, in **init**
raise AttributeError('A text object must have a text attribute')

AttributeError: A text object must have a text attribute

```
from vpython import *

h= 1.0/365.0; m= 1.0/332946.0; ep= 0.017; T=1.0
G= 4.0*pi*pi; k=G*m
E= -pow(pi*pi*k*k*m/2.0/T/T,1.0/3.0)
L2= m*k*k*(ep*ep-1)/2.0/E
rmin= L2/(1+ep)/m/k

x1=rmin; y1=0.0; vx=0.0; vy=sqrt(2/m*(E+k/rmin))
Tiempo=text(pos=(0,0.9,0), depth=-0.01, color=color.green, height=0.1)

Sol=sphere(pos=(0,0,0),radius=0.1,color=color.yellow)
Tierra=sphere(por=(x1,y1,0), radius=0.05, color=color.blue)

def fx(x,y):
    r3=pow(x*x+y*y,1.5)
    return(-G/r3*x)
def fy(x,y):
     r3=pow(x*x+y*y,1.5)
     return(-G/r3*y)

x0=x1-vx*h+h*h+fx(x1,y1)/2
y0=y1-vy*h+h*h+fy(x1,y1)/2

for t in range(366):
    rate(50)
    x2=2*x1-x0+h*h+fx(x1,y1)
    y2=2*y1-y0+h*h+fy(x1,y1)
    Tierra.pos=(x2,y2,0)
    S=str(t*h)[0:5]
    Tiempo.text= 't = ' + S
    print('t = ',S,',x = ',x2,',y = ',y2)
    x0 = x1; x1=x2; y0=y1; y1=y2
```

Comment: Nunca he usado anaconda o vpython pero... `Tiempo=text(text="algo", pos=(0,0.9,0), depth=-0.01, color=color.green, height=0.1)` imagino que lo soluciona, ya que el error te dice exactamente lo que falla.

Answer (score 1):

text() necesita el atributo text para output:

```
Tiempo=text(text='mitexto', pos=(0,0.9,0), depth=-0.01, color=color.green, height=0.1)
```

Es muy probable que después de poner el atributo text te salga un error en 'pos', eso es porque 'pos' debe ser un vector, entonces se solucionaría así:

```
Tiempo=text(text='mitexto', pos=vector(0,0.9,0), depth=-0.01, color=color.green, height=0.1)
```

Al final solo agregamos *text* y cambiamos el valor de *pos* a vector

También puedes revisar la documentación: https://www.glowscript.org/docs/VPythonDocs/text.html